# Using React to call Nested API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I had the following JSON file:

```
{
"farmer": [
{
"crops": "corn"
}
],
"activities":{
"hobbies": "swimming"
},
"name: Todd"
}
```

I would like to know how to make calls to them using React. My best attempt is as shown below.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
var selfish = this;
$.get('~~someurl~~', function(data){
selfish.setState(data);
});
},

render: function(){
return (<div>
<p>{this.state.name}</p>
<p>{this.state.activities.hobbies}</p>
<p>{this.state.farmer[0].crops}</p>
</div>)
}
```

I get that the first one `{this.state.name}` will run as it has been written. However, I am uncertain as to how to express the final two `{this.state.activities.hobbies}` and `{this.state.farmer[0].crops}` using the React syntax.

I have written them out in hopefully a way that expresses what I am trying to achieve with each call.

EDIT: The specific error that results from the latter two state that they are undefined.

EDIT: So I got the second one working by adding an empty initial state.

```
getInitialState: function(){
return {activities: '', farmer: ''}
}
```

However, this leaves the last one, which still returns an error.

Comment: Anything between the `{...}` is just normal JavaScript (there is no specific "React syntax"). `this.state.activities.hobbies` etc will work as long as the data exists. I assume that on the initial render the data doesn't exist. In that case you first have to think about how the UI should look like if the data is not present. Testing for the existence of the data / property works as usual, e.g. `this.state.activities && this.state.activities.hobbies`. There is nothing React specific about it.

Comment: Then I guess the question I have is how to go about loading these calls during page load, just as I would with `{this.state.name}`. Because `{this.state.name}` loads just as soon as I render.

Comment: They *are* executed on initial render. But because `this.state.activities` doesn't exist the first time, you will get an error. So you either have to check beforehand whether the value exist (and render something depending on that check) or you have to provide a default state to the component, e.g. with an empty `this.state.activities` object. Here is a simplified example of the issue you are experiencing: `var state = {}; console.log(state.activities.hobbies);` This will throw an error because `state` doesn't have any properties. Now, I can either add an initial value or test before logging.

Comment: Cool. I took what you said and returned an empty `activities` on initial load. Now, I'm still unsure of the last part `{this.state.farmer[0].crops}`. Having an empty `farmer: ''` on initial state does not solve this.

Comment: Well, `this.state.farmer[0].crops` expects `farmer` to be an an array containing an object. `farmer: ''` sets `farmer` to an empty string instead. Type `var farmer = ''; console.log(farmer[0])` in your browser's console and see what the result is. If you go with the default state, then you need to initialize the state with values similar to the ones you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using componentDidMount when you should use componentWillMount. Check out [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) on these lifecycle methods.

This is what the documentation says about componentDidMount

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately
>   after the initial rendering occurs.

Which means when you first render your states are not declared unless you have used getInitialState before (another lifecycle method).

I simply did this:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.setState({
        "farmer": [
            {
            "crops": "corn"
            }
        ],
        "activities":{
            "hobbies": "swimming"
        },
        "name": "Todd"
    });
},
```

and I was able to use `this.state.farmer[0].crops` in my render method

EDIT:

To be clear. If you need to retrieve the data after you rendered the component then you need to specify default values for the states that you use in render. This can be achieved using getInitialState:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        "farmer": [
            {
                "crops": DEFAULT_VALUE
            }
        ],
        "activities":{
            "hobbies": DEFAULT_VALUE
        },
        "name": DEFAULT_VALUE
    });
},
```

Comment: So I am trying to place an empty initial state. Where I did `activities: ''`, how would I do that for `farmer[0].crops`?

Comment: This is the wrong solution. Using `componentDidMount` is correct, since the OP is making an Ajax request. Using `componentWillMount` won't help here. I mean, you *can* use it, but it won't help, since Ajax is asynchronous. If you want to provide an initial state, do that with `getInitialState`.

Comment: In the answer I also mention that to have them declared before you can use getInitialState. I am taking a broader approach to explaining what to do